# I wanted to see data for next 7 days from the selected day in power bi dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am having a date column and I am using it in a filter visual and I wanted to get the graph data for the next 7 days from the selected date from the filter, for example, I have selected the 1 dec 2019 now the graph will show next 7 days of data only.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly from the date filter. However, there are workarounds using some measures and a calendar table. The steps to be followed are highlighted in the below link along with a sample Power BI file:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-show-next-2-days-of-selected-date/td-p/333945

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the filter context.
I would proceed as follow:

```
[Measure] :=
// take the selected date from the filter
// we could have used SELECTEDVALUE but it is less robust
VAR _SelectedDate = MAX('Calendar'[Date]) + 1
RETURN
CALCULATE(
SUM('FactTable'[Quantity],
// we need to modify the Calendar filtere context
ALL('Calendar'),
'Calendar'[Date] IN {_SelectedDate, _SelectedDate+1, _SelectedDate+2, _SelectedDate+3, _SelectedDate+4, _SelectedDate+5, _SelectedDate + 6}
)
```

We could have used a complex comparison operator such as '>' and <' but 
they are generate callback operations negatively impact the performance.